# can reduce task accept compressed data in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-partitioning

we see that map can accept and output compressed and uncompressed data. I was going through cloudera training and teacher mentioned that reduce task input has to be in form o key value and thus can't work on compressed data.

Is that right? If thats right, how can i handle network latency when transferring bug data from shuffler/partitioner to reduce task.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Mapper` can output compressed data, of course, the `Reducer` can accept compressed data. This is transparent to both of them, so the output is compressed and uncompressed automatically.

I think he/she must have been saying that Hadoop must uncompress that compressed input for you since the `Reducer` is not expecting compressed data that it has to uncompress itself.

`Reducer`s can also output compressed data, and that's controlled separately. You can control the codec. You can also read compressed data as input to a `Mapper` automatically.

There are some catches though: for example, `gzip` compressed files can't be split by a `Mapper`, and that's bad for parallelism. But a `bzip` compressed file can be split in some cases.

Comment: thanks for your message Sean. How can reducer's input be uncompressed before it actually sees it? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can.
Just add this on your driver class' main method:

```
  Configuration conf = new Configuration();
  conf.setBoolean("mapred.compress.map.output", true);
  conf.setClass("mapred.map.output.compression.codec", SnappyCodec.class, CompressionCodec.class);
```